# Vuetify text color variants

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use one of the color variants for text, how can I do this? I have tried:

`<h2 class="red--text lighten-1--text">My Address</h2>`

`<h2 class="red--text lighten-1">My Address</h2>`

`<h2 class="red-lighten-1--text">My Address</h2>`

and many other variations, but I can only seem to get the text to go the base red color, not the variants listed [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/colors#classes). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`class="red--text text--lighten-5"`

from the docs

> Text colors also support darken and lighten variants using text--{lighten|darken}-{n}

or you can inspect elements and pick up classes from there

Comment: Damn, I see it now, not sure why I didnt read that line. Thanks mate.

Comment: and where do you set the default text color of the whole app? cant seem to find a variable for that! Vuetify adds 0.87 opacity, but I'm not sure where this happens

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing

Answer (score 10):

You must use it this way:

```html
<h2 class="red--text text--lighten-1">My Address</h2>
```

For `darken-{n}` and `lighten-{n}`, pre-pend `text` instead of appending it.

Actually there is even an [example](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/colors/textClasses.vue) almost as exactly as yours in the documentation:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong class="red--text text--lighten-1">inciderint</strong> definitionem est ea, explicari prodesset eam id. Mazim doctus vix an. <span class="indigo--text text--darken-2">Amet causae probatus nec ex</span>.
  </div>
</template>
```

Demo [here](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/NozWwZ?&editable=true&editors=101):

```html
<h2 class="red--text text--lighten-1">My Address</h2>.
<h2 class="red--text text--lighten-2"> My Address</h2>.
```

and result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Vuetify 3 the old answers are deprecated.

> Variants are no longer a separate class, it must be combined with a color.

You should write it in this way:

```
<h2 class="text-red-lighten-1">My Address</h2>.
```

Take a look at [Vuetify Migration guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#theme)

Comment: ```text-red-lighten-1``` does work, but ```text-primary-lighten-1``` does not seem to do anything